# I want to have privileged user access to a menu item in web2py

Tags: web2py

So my first user is going to be the privileged user.

I added this code to the default controller, but it does not seem to work.

Please give some pointers on how to make it work?

```
@auth.requires_membership('user_1')
def adm():
     response.menu+= [ (T('Admin?'), False, URL(c='appadmin'), [])]
```

Comment: Are you saying the menu item does not appear when 'user_1' is logged in and visits the /default/adm URL, or are you expecting that menu item to appear when on some other page (which won't be the case, as it is only added when visiting the /default/adm page)?

Comment: For the admin user, I want the "ADMIN?" menu item to be present on all pages whenever logged in. Otherwise it should not be there at all. It is working for the admin user but it is appearing for the normal user as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `models/menu.py` add following lines:

```
if auth.has_membership(role="admin"):
    response.menu.extend([(T('Admin?'), False, URL(c='appadmin'), [])])
```

So `Admin?` menu will be shown only when user with role "admin" is logged in.